# Combining identical into one row in R

Tags: r, merge, similarity

So I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   Animal    Food   LikeScore   
1   cat      fish      98
2   cat      milk      72
3   cat     shrimp     88
4   dog     steak      99
5   dog      poo       55
```

I would like to generate a data frame that combines animals into one row, with a list of all the foods they like into another column on the same row (regardless of the score):

```
    Animal          Food
1    cat      fish, milk, shrimp
2    dog      steak, poo
```

Is there a function in R that can do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: See something like `aggregate(Food ~ Animal, DF, paste, sep = ", ")`.

Comment: Although I think you need `collapse = ', '` in stead of `sep = ', '`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use `plyr` for this:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Animal), summarize, Food = paste(Food, collapse = ', '))
```

Note that the code is untested because your example is not reproducible. However, an example using `mtcars` shows that it works:

```
ddply(mtcars, .(gear), summarize, carb = paste(carb, collapse = ', '))
  gear                                        carb
1    3 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2
2    4          4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2
3    5                               2, 2, 4, 6, 8
```